# MySQL Update JSON value if condition matches

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.7, and I have a table containing measurements (the actual table has a diffrent purpose but this is meant as an MRE):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MyObjects`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `MyObjects` (
  `uuid` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `json` json DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `MyObjects`
--

LOCK TABLES `MyObjects` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `MyObjects` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `MyObjects` VALUES (
  '7c4b9fab-95fd-494f-bd70-5739c44acb97',
  '{\"measurements\": [
    {\"temperature\": 30}, 
    {\"temperature\": 43}
  ]}'
);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `MyObjects` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

So the column contains json like:

```
{"measurements": [{"temperature": 30},{"temperature": 43}]}
```

And I want to update all temperatures to 40 where they are bigger then 40. I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE MyObjects 
SET json=JSON_SET(json, '$.measurements[*].temperature', 40) 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.measurements[*].temperature') > 40
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR 3149 (42000): In this situation, path expressions may not 
contain the * and ** tokens or an array range.
```

I understand that the issue is that my WHERE clause needs to refer to each individual element of the array. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It's too hard to replace multiple values in nested JSON using JSON functions in MySQL. Use regular expressions:

```sql
UPDATE MyObjects
SET `json` = REGEXP_REPLACE(
  `json`, 
  '\\s*"temperature"\\s*:\\s*[4-9][0-9](\\s|,)*', 
  '"temperature": 40'
);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fcc85a13f084ee905c816f16c413671b